# Reading csv file in Python and create a dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to read a csv file in python 27 to create a dictionary. CSV file looks like-

> SI1440269,SI1320943,SI1321085 
>   SI1440270,SI1320943,SI1321085,SI1320739
>   SI1440271,SI1320943
>   SI1440273,SI1321058,SI1320943,SI1320943

Number of entries in each row are not fixed. First column entries should be my keys. My code -

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('test.csv'))

result = {}
for column in reader:
    key = column[0]
    if key in result:
        pass
    result[key] = column[1:]
print result
```

Output:

> {'SI1440273': ['SI1321058', 'SI1320943', 'SI1320943'], '': ['', '', ''], 'SI1440271': ['SI1320943', '', ''], 'SI1440270': ['SI1320943', 'SI1321085', 'SI1320739'], 'SI1440269': ['SI1320943', 'SI1321085', '']}

How can I get rid of null values in the output?
Also, how can I have my key values in the output to be in the same order as in csv file?

Edit:
I want single row per 'key'

Comment: Just for the record it is not really a csv file.

Comment: Also for the record, I believe the variable you define as column is actually a row :)

Comment: I am not sure if understand what is the expected output here. Do you want to keep only a single row per "key"?

Comment: I just ran your program and I'm getting different results: `{'SI1440270 SI1320943 SI1321085 SI1320739 SI1440271 SI1320943': [], 'SI1440273 SI1321058 SI1320943 SI1320943': [], 'SI1440269 SI1320943 SI1321085': []}`. Can you explain a little more what you want here?

Comment: @hobenkr ; I want single row per 'key'. Mr. A 's code worked well except that key values in the output are in reverse order compared to that in csv file.

Comment: @hobenkr How is it a row? Care to explain?

Comment: Your for loop iterates over each row in your csv file, not each column. You can see this if you put a print statement at the top of your loop: `print(column)`. This will print a row of your file, not a column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('test.csv'))

result = {row[0]:row[1:] for row in reader if row and row[0]}
print result
```

if you want further more to eliminate null in values then do as bellow

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('test.csv'))

result = {row[0]:[i for i in row[1:] if i] for row in reader if row and row[0]}
print result
```

To preserve the order of entry

```
from collections import OrderedDict
result = OrderedDict()
for row in reader:
   if row and row[0]:
      result[row[0]]=[i for i in row[1:] if i]

# print result
for key in result:
   print key,":" ,result[key]
```

Comment: This solved my problem partially. I want my key values in the output to be in the same order as in csv file. Its not happening with your code.

Comment: from collections import OrderedDict and use it

Comment: Used but didn't work. Code- `import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
result = OrderedDict()
reader = csv.reader(open('test.csv'))
result = {row[0]:[i for i in row[1:] if i] for row in reader if row and row[0]}
print result`

Comment: This is Just for your knowledge dictionary in python is a hash table which don't preserve any order where as if you want to preserve order of entry of key then use `OrderedDict` from `collections` I have added third sample code make use of it.

Comment: is it compulsory that the word 'OrderedDict' comes at the beginning of the output?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `csv.DictReader` as follows:

```
import csv

result = {}
with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=" ", fieldnames=["id"], restkey="data")
    for row in reader:
        print row
        result[row["id"]] = row["data"]

print result
```

This would give you a per-row dictionary solution, so you could process it a line at a time. I also then append them all into one single `result` dictionary.

From this you will get the following output:

```
{'data': ['SI1320943', 'SI1321085'], 'id': 'SI1440269'}
{'data': ['SI1320943', 'SI1321085', 'SI1320739', 'SI1440271', 'SI1320943'], 'id': 'SI1440270'}
{'data': ['SI1321058', 'SI1320943', 'SI1320943'], 'id': 'SI1440273'}
{'SI1440273': ['SI1321058', 'SI1320943', 'SI1320943'], 'SI1440270': ['SI1320943', 'SI1321085', 'SI1320739', 'SI1440271', 'SI1320943'], 'SI1440269': ['SI1320943', 'SI1321085']}
```

Answer (score 2):

As already noted this is not CSV - so readline and split would be more appropriate and use OrderedDict to keep input order:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
result = OrderedDict()
with open('test.csv') as f:
    for row  in f:
        row=row.strip().split()
        key = row[0]
        result[key] = row[1:]
print result
```

Comment: Why it is not CSV. Care to explain?

Comment: CSV = Comma Separated Value -  so fields are separated by comma, here I see that they are separated by space - so split is easier - csv reader gives result as  noted in comment by @hobenkr